# Google adsense reference

Tags: php, drupal, adsense, pay-per-click

My client has a Google Adsense account and one ad-campaign with several ads under it.

The client needs to identify the incoming users who come through clicking each ad.

The client uses Drupal PHP site.

Is there a possibility to track incoming users who come through Google ads?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). From the [Features page](http://www.google.com/analytics/features.html):

> #### Integrated with AdWords and AdSense
>
> Optimize your AdWords performance with post-click data on your keywords, search queries, match type and more. AdSense reports show publishers which site content generates the most revenue.

Comment: No my client need to capture the campaign id and save the details under particular user in his DB for future reference.

Comment: I think there may be some privacy issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add arguments to the urls used in the adds:

```
http://example.com
```

changed to

```
http://example.com?google=ad123
```

You can then in your Drupal check for the presence of the google argument in the `$_REQUEST` variable and act accordingly. This should be done in `hook_boot`.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

You may use events, and you may add custom parameters to them, but they didn't work for me on the first shot and i gave up. If you figure out how to use them please post a story on how you did that:)